# I don't understand this message: Error in x > n : comparison of these types is not implemented

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, hypothesis-test

I am attempting to run a function (a z-test) over a dataframe  by first defining the function and then in a seperate step apply it iteratively across all rows. The goal is to form new colunms that include the p-value of that z-test, for the given target-variables. I can't seem to get the iteration to work as I keep getting this unfamiliar error message.

I define the function:
`functionname <- function(V1,V2,V3,V4){...}`

This step seems to work, I can input values and am getting a correct result.  My code for the iteration looks as follows:

```
for (i in rownames(df)){

df[i, "newvariableA"] <- functionname(df[i,"V1"],df[i,"V2"],df[i,"V3"],df[i,"V4"])
df[i, "newvariableB"] <- functionname(df[i,"V1"],df[i,"V2"],df[i,"V3"],df[i,"V4"])
}
```

Which produces the erorr message

```
Error in x > n : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

I hope you guys could give me a pointer as to why this error is produced or to an alternative approach.

Thanks!

Edit: More info on the function output:

```
functionname <- function(V1,V2,V3,V4){
 ges1 <- V1/sqrt(2)
 ges2 <- V2/sqrt(2)
 t1 <- (V3/100)*ges1
 t2 <- (V4/100)*ges2
 sig <- prop.test(c(t1,t2),c(ges1,ges2),correct=FALSE)$p.value

 sig <- round(sig,4)
 if (sig>0.05){
   sig <- "ns"
 } else if (sig==0){
   sig <- ".0000"
 } else{
   sig <- substr(toString(sig),start=2,stop=100)
 }
 return(sig)
}
```

Comment: What is the result of your function?

Comment: The function returns a string, giving either the calculated p-value (if < 0.5) or just "ns" (if > 0.5)

Comment: Added the relevant section of the function to main question, thanks!

Comment: Understood, the function is in the main comment now

Comment: puzzling, not familiar with this specific error... ```x``` and ```n``` are both present in ```prop.test```, but your function works when fed values. Looking at your for-loop:
does ```df$newvariableA <- functionname(df[i,"V1"],df[i,"V2"],df[i,"V3"],df[i,"V4"])``` work? the loop is already specified to do it row by row due to the  (i in rownames(df))

Comment: Hi @Omniswitcher thanks for your reply. The suggested method is unfortunately not working out. Error message being `Error in `[.tbl_df`(df, i, "V1") : object 'i' not found`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i,"newvariableA"] <- ztestd(df[i,"V1"],df[i,"V2"],df[i,"V3"],df[i,"V4"])
}
```

Comment: Yields a new error, with the old one still there:    `Error in x > n : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:rownames(df) :
  numerical expression has 204 elements: only the first used`

Comment: Try this , noticing your function returns one output.

Comment: Now its back to just the "Error in x>n"

Comment: try `dput(df)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem that I saw long ago when I got a class of R few years back
and there wasn't any solution to this at that time.
so we used DF as a tibble rather than as a dataframe then problem was gone I didn't get it how that fixed the problem but it did if you don't have any constraints to use df as a dataframe you can try it and use as tibble

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the error message

Comment: Please provide an example with code